# Want to create Regex Pattern

Tags: regex

I want to create a Regex Pattern which can match the following patterns:

1) `tail-test-str1`

2) `tail-test1-test2-str2`

3) `tail-test-test3-str1`

I have tried `tail-(test|test1)` in this first 2 content of string gets validate, after that for remaining string how to create a regex pattern I don't have any idea.

Comment: Are these 3 strings the _only_ possible matches, or are they just examples?

Comment: Please, show how `test1`, `test2`, `str1` .. look like, I guess you don't want to match them literally. Else a simple `^tail(?-test\d*)*-str\d+$` will do the job. Add also the tool/programing language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this pattern `tail-(?:test\d?-)*str\d?`

Explanation:

`tail-` - match `tail-` literally

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`test` - match `test` literally

`\d?` - match digit zero or one time

`-` - match hyphen literally

`*` - match preceeding pattern zero or more times

`str` - match `str` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGX1gy/2)

Comment: Thanks for Answer, Just one more thing I need to ask, How can i make this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BaTgl/2) work for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If these 3 strings be the only exact matches, then this pattern might be the best we can do here:

```
^tail-(?:test(?:-test3)?-str1|test1-test2-str2)$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way could be:

```
^tail(?-\w+)+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4BaTgl/6)